# WebStorm will not run Jest but Mocha when click on run button on left gutter

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, webstorm

I want to run Jest tests from the WebStorm's gutter (the green triangle icons on the left side, by the line numbers).

[image]

But it always opens Mocha config dialog:

[image]

My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "beetrack-fe",
  "version": "4.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Front End App for Beetrack",
  "author": "Hung Truong",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "BABEL_ENV=build ENV=prd ./node_modules/.bin/quasar build",
    "build_dev": "BABEL_ENV=build ENV=dev ./node_modules/.bin/quasar build",
    "build_qa": "BABEL_ENV=build ENV=qa ./node_modules/.bin/quasar build",
    "build_stg": "BABEL_ENV=build ENV=stg ./node_modules/.bin/quasar build",
    "dev": "BABEL_ENV=build ENV=local ./node_modules/.bin/quasar dev",
    "test": "BABEL_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/jest --updateSnapshot",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "concurrently:dev:jest": "concurrently \"quasar dev\" \"jest --watch\"",
    "electron-chromedriver": "./node_modules/electron-chromedriver/bin/chromedriver --port=9515 --url-base=wd/hub --verbose",
    "selenium:install": "./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install",
    "selenium:start": "./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone start",
    "serve:test:coverage": "./node_modules/.bin/quasar serve test/jest/coverage/lcov-report/ --port 8788",
    "styleguide": "vue-cli-service styleguidist",
    "styleguide:build": "vue-cli-service styleguidist:build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "1.1.4",
    "axios": "0.19.0",
    "hooper": "^0.3.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lscache": "^1.3.0",
    "quasar": "1.0.3",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.5.13",
    "vue-fragment": "^1.5.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/app": "1.0.2",
    "@quasar/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing": "1.0.0",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-e2e-webdriver": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest": "1.0.0",
    "@vue/cli": "^3.9.2",
    "@vue/cli-service": "3.9.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.2",
    "eslint": "6.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "5.2.3",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-styleguidist": "^3.15.4",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "cordovaId": "org.cordova.quasar.app",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 8.9.0",
    "npm": ">= 5.6.0",
    "yarn": ">= 1.6.0"
  },
  "productName": "Beetrack"
}
```

I already config Jest so that it can run for all test files by the run button on the toolbar. But it does not work for the gutter run button.

Please guild me how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE uses the test runners listed in `package.json` when running tests from gutter, and, when several runners are there, it gives certain ones a priority. There is currently no way to specify a test runner explicitly( Please follow [WEB-28397](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28397) for updates.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working. My package.json already include `"jest": "^24.9.0"` as devDependencies and the test scrips is `"test": "BABEL_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/jest --updateSnapshot"`. What am I missing?

Comment: try commenting out `mocha` dependency in your `package.json`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, there isn't `mocha` in my `package.json`. I updated the question for including my `package.json`. Please refer to it

Comment: it's strange... Do you have any existing **Mocha** run configurations in **Run | Edit configurations**? If yes, please try deleting them all